# PHP mssql_connect problem

Tags: php

Dear Experts;
I have installed PHP Fast-cgi on IIS 7 . I am using Windows R2 2008 Enterprise. mssql_connect function doesnt run. 
I tried to install ntwdblib.dll on C:\windows\SysWOW64 and I called regsvr32.exe ntvlib.dll in command prompt. But I cant it.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

"I tried to install ntwdblib.dll on C:\windows\SysWOW64 and I called regsvr32.exe ntvlib.dll in command prompt. But I cant it. "

What error message showed?
Instead of pasting "regsvr32.exe ntvlib.dll" into the run window, type "cmd" [without quote marks] into the run box, then type the command in the cmd.